# lapply: Error in inherits(x, "Source") : empty directory

Tags: r, machine-learning, lapply, document-classification

I am studying document classification by replicating a tutorial. We are using candidate speeches as training material. However, I am getting the following error while replicating the tutorial:

```
> tdm <- lapply(candidates, generateTDM, path = pathname)
Error in inherits(x, "Source") : empty directory
```

I have confirmed that the error message is not caused by the directory path. I speculate that saving candidate speeches in an .RTF text format (in MacBook) causes the error message, and .RTF may not be compatible with how my code calls for ANSI encoding under generateTDM variable.

```
s.cor <- Corpus(DirSource(directory = s.dir, encoding = "ANSI"))
```

I have tried **encoding = ASCII** with unsuccessful result. How can I get rid of the error message? Here is the full code:

```
library(tm)
library(plyr)
library(class)

# Initialize the Environment
libs <- c("tm", "plyr", "class")
lapply(libs, require, character.only = TRUE)

# Set Options
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Set Parameters
candidates <- c("hitler", "drum")
pathname <- "/Path Name/Is Correct/Help"

# Clean Text
cleanCorpus <- function(corpus) {
  corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
  corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus.tmp, strepwhitespace)
  corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus.tmp, tolower)
  corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus.tmp, removewords, stopwords("english"))
  return(corpus.tmp)

}

# Build Term Document Matrix
generateTDM <- function(cand, path) {
  s.dir <- sprintf("%s/%s", path, cand)
  s.cor <- Corpus(DirSource(directory = s.dir, encoding = "ANSI"))
  s.cor.cl <- cleanCorpus(s.cor)
  s.tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(s.cor.cl)

  s.tdm <- removeSparseTerms(s.tdm, 0.7)
  result <- list(name = cand, tdm = s.tdm)

}

tdm <- lapply(candidates, generateTDM, path = pathname)
```

Comment: What of this code uses the `plyr` or `class` packages? Why are you using *both* `library` and `require`? (I recommend against using `require`, and when used this way it is not robust to problems. Good reads on this topic: https://yihui.name/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/ and http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html#search-path.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I believe `plyr` and `class` functions are introduced in later parts of the tutorial. And, thanks for the good read. Looks more like I am learning machine than machine learning.